# kvm killed by oomkiller

Tags: linux, debian, kvm, qemu, out-of-memory

kvm version: `QEMU emulator version 1.1.2 (qemu-kvm-1.1.2+dfsg-6+deb7u3, Debian), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard`
libvirtd version: `libvirtd (libvirt) 0.9.12.3`
debian version: `7.5`

I'm running multiple VMs on a 16GB RAM machine, all together they use ~9GB RAM.

Every now and then the linux oom killer comes over and kills a process. I guess it chooses the process using most of the memory - in this case a 6GB Windows VM:
`[431215.778365] Out of memory: Kill process 25086 (kvm) score 192 or sacrifice child`

IMHO the machine shouldn't be in an OOM Situation as there are ~6.6GB cached memory available. You can see the memory distribution and the resulting oom kill here:

[image: memory distribution]

I now have set the `oom_adj` for the pid of the kvms to `-17`, so the oom-killer won't kill this process.

But I'm still failing to understand why the kernel thinks it has to kill a process and won't go ahead and free some cached memory.

- Can anyone explain why this happens?
- Can you tell me how I can prevent the oom killer from killing my kvm processes without knowing the PID?

Comment: Sounds like this bug to me: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=903432

Comment: Also check for a full `tmpfs`, depending how you check it may count as cache/buffer even though it can't be freed short of swapping it.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable the `OOM Killer` for the particular process with:

```
for p in $(pidof kvm qemu-system32_x64); do
  echo -n '-17' > /proc/$p/oom_adj
done
```

or by flavor `oom_score adj`.

However:

> Out of memory: Kill process 25086 (kvm) score 192 or sacrifice child

In your case is to set also to `192`.

See also [Taming the OOM Killer](http://lwn.net/Articles/317814/)

In any case, you should check also what causes the memory overflow, since the OOM Killer will kill other important processes.

Often it is observed a phenomenon called `overtuning`. In this case the `overcommit_memory` as described [here](https://plumbr.eu/blog/out-of-memory-kill-process-or-sacrifice-child).

Source [proc filesystems](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

**oom_adj:**

```
For backwards compatibility with previous kernels, /proc/<pid>/oom_adj may also
be used to tune the badness score.  Its acceptable values range from -16
(OOM_ADJUST_MIN) to +15 (OOM_ADJUST_MAX) and a special value of -17
(OOM_DISABLE) to disable oom killing entirely for that task.  Its value is
scaled linearly with /proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj.
```

**oom_score_adj:**

```
The value of /proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj is added to the badness score before it
is used to determine which task to kill.  Acceptable values range from -1000
(OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MIN) to +1000 (OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MAX).  This allows userspace to
polarize the preference for oom killing either by always preferring a certain
task or completely disabling it.  The lowest possible value, -1000, is
equivalent to disabling oom killing entirely for that task since it will always
report a badness score of 0.
```

Comment: First of: oom_adj is deprecated, the new file is oom_score_adj. Also this doesn't solve the issue that there is cached memory avaliable (alongside 16GB of swap) which is never touched.

Comment: thanks, completed. Did you scored to 192 as it is written? What causes the OOM Killer to kill tasks?